# What's the difference between terminology and single word requests?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag info for [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) indicates the difference between it and [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) and [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), but doesn't distinguish between it and [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Why is [Term for an event being referred to by its location or date](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53863/term-for-an-event-being-referred-to-by-its-location-or-date) tagged [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) but [Is there a term for referring to an organization by its city rather than by its name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27163/is-there-a-term-for-referring-to-an-organization-by-its-city-rather-than-by-its) tagged [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)? Is one of them incorrectly tagged?

Answer (score 1):

The description for [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) says:

> Topics related to the body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, theory, profession, etc.

I think the difference is that in one case, you are asking about a technical term, and when to use it ([terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)); in the other case, you want to use a single word instead of a phrase, and you ask which word to use describing the context.
So, when you ask when the term *metonymy* is used, the tag should be [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), but when you ask for a single word to use instead of "fantastic event that leaves you in a such catatonic state that somebody could steal the chair you are sitting on without you noticing it," that should be tagged [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request).

As you are referring to another question that is tagged [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) in your own question, I think it should be tagged with the same tag.